# joi.object(),pattern(joi.string(),joi.string()) is not working

Tags: node.js, joi

I want to validate the dynamic key name of an object of the request body, but giving an error

Sample portion of request body schema:-

```
menuMappings: joi.object().pattern(
                                joi.string(), joi.object().keys({
                                    iconName: joi.string(),
                                    uri: joi.string()
                                })
                            )
```

Error:- menuMappings is not allowed

this error is coming only when I m using `.pattern( joi.string(),`
if I use `.pattern(/./,` then it will work fine.
Other regex and joi schema is not working only `/./` is working.

Requirement:-
I want to use `/(?i)\b(?:theme|logo)\b/` or joi schema which will except theme or local as key name and it will be non-case sensitivity

Comment: Please post an example of your data. Thanks

Comment: If `menuMapping is not allowed` is your error.. you realise you've defined it as `menuMappings` (plural) in the schema?

Comment: My mistake it is menuMappings